# Use external process image library in Java Spring MVC web server

Tags: java

Basically the backstory is that there's a requirement coming from my customer to apply image compression (for png files) for user uploaded files in order to make files much smaller.

What I found is a pngquant library, which is an external linux executable that accepts a file as an input and produces another file as an output. I googled for a native image compression library, but none of what I found gave such a good compression/quality ratio.

**So the question is**: is it a really Java-way to use external processes for manipulating with the user content in terms of service stability, security and other issues? How do you guys cope with these kind of requests?